# What are ways to keep data synchronized between a C# WPF application and SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, service, synchronization

I am working on an application where users in a local network are notified when a "record" from the database changes. So if person "A" changes Record 1 and person "B" has Record 1 in their view, person "B" will be notified that Record 1 has changed.
We are currently using what is called a "duplex" service to send these notifications through a WCF service. The service is rather slow and ideally we would like to remove it. Are there any ways to keep data in real-time (or close to it) for users, when another user has updated the database?

Comment: It sounds like you are auditing the database. Is the audit in real time? Is the polling on a timer. There are many factors that can contribute to a notification delay. I would find where the bottle neck lies before you dive in and make wholesale changes.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the current design of your system. Do all applications connect to the same WCF service? Does this service send out notifications to all the applications when one is updated. It seems complex.

Comment: All apps connect to the same service, when something is changed in the database the service raises an event and then each client that listens to said event is alerted of changes. It is indeed very complex!

Comment: Maybe instead of removing service you should find out why is it slow and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to replace your notification service my suggestion would be to use [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) to keep your clients synchronized with your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once and ended up crossing over to a NoSql cloud solution called Firebase with the Firesharp library. [Firebase - Features](https://firebase.google.com/features/), [Firesharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp).

It is blindingly fast and actually really easy to use. So if your application is still quite small and the business risk of migrating to a NoSql setup is small it might be a worthwhile solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately this is a huge application so I don't think this would work in our circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

How long they keep the record in view? 
What is the mechanism that is checking if the value changed?
what kind of client application are you using?

You could create an async method that is validating the status of the item the user is using against a nodejs server that will be querying the db, for that particular record, reply with the value and the async method can validate if the current value is different from the one from the DB and then it can inform the user or update the record.
Those have small footprint and should run more efficiently.